# Is there a way to access Nullable<T>.Value without performing a Nullable<T>.HasValue check?

Tags: c#

I have some nullable values and would like to avoid exceptions when accessing their values. The following shows an example of what I want to achieve. I currently have

```
DateTime? dt = null;
    
if(dt != null) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt?.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));  
}
```

but I've seen that nullable values have a `Value` property. The equivalent would be

```
DateTime? dt = null;
    
if(dt.HasValue) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt.Value.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")); 
}
```

Is there a way I can simplify the code to something like this?

```
DateTime? dt = null;
    
Console.WriteLine(dt.Value?.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
```

so that it only runs `.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")` if `dt` is not null?

Comment: GetValueOrDefault() might an option depending on what you expect

Comment: `dt?.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")`

Comment: Should the last line of your question be _so that it only runs `Console.WriteLine` if `dt` is not null?_?

Answer (score 2):

With pattern matching (since c# 7.0) you can write

```
DateTime? dt = null;
if (dt is DateTime d) {
    Console.WriteLine(d.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
} else {
    Console.WriteLine("dt is null");
}
```

This type pattern works, because `null` has no type and `null is T` always returns `false`. If the value is not null, then it is casted to `T` and assigned to the new variable `d` of type `T`.

You can also use an empty property pattern (empty, because we do not want to test a property). For a property pattern to be true, a non-null object is assumed. Therefore, this tests for `not null`.

```
if (dt is {} d) {
    // d is a non-nullable DateTime and of course dt was not null here.
}
```

But I must admit that this is less readable.

See also:

- [Pattern Matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching) (C# 7)
- [Do more with patterns in C# 8.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/do-more-with-patterns-in-c-8-0/)
- [What's new in C# 9.0 / Pattern matching enhancements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#pattern-matching-enhancements)

---

You can also use string interpolation, this is especially useful if there is more than the date alone. This has the advantage that you do not need to test whether `dt` is null because you are not calling `ToString`:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Date: {dt:yyyyMMddHHmmss}");
```

Comment: I think this overcomplicates things. A simple null check would suffice.

Comment: Agreed. I don't think I would ever use pattern matching for this case.

Comment: Using the null coalescing operator `dt?.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")` without an additional `if` is indeed easier, if you just want to write an empty line when the value is null, but if you want to write nothing or to do something else in an `else` case, then the pattern matching is very handy as it does test and cast and declare and assign to a new variable all at the same time. It does 4 things; this makes it very powerful.

Comment: I don't disagree with what you're saying, it's a valid answer, but in relation to what the OP is asking, I think it's overkill, hence my previous comment.

Comment: Yeh, but isn't `if (dt != null)` easier?

Comment: This solution also may produce an unexpected blank line on console when `dt` is `null`.

Comment: @RafaelBiz, no because then the if-statement will not enter, because `null` is not `DateTime`. Note that `d` is `DateTime` and not `Nullable<DateTime>`. I added an else case to make this point clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `Value` property and just call it on the nullable itself:

```
DateTime? dt = null;
    
Console.WriteLine(dt?.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"));
```

Comment: This may produce an unexpected blank line on the console when `dt` is `null`.